# touchmove/MSPointerMove event not firing in Windows 8

Tags: javascript, touch, windows-8, tablet, internet-explorer-10

I'm just a lowly uC programmer who's trying to put together a little web interface for his boss.  I've got everything working so far except being able to select a square on a canvas using touch input.

**This is on a Samsung Slate 7 tablet running Windows 8 and IE10**

I've distilled the code down to pretty much the bare essentials here:

```
var cxt;
var c;

window.onload = function () {

c = document.getElementById('displayCanvas');

cxt = c.getContext('2d');


/*
c.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", mouseUp, false);
c.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", mouseMove, false);
c.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", mouseDown, false);
*/
c.addEventListener("touchend", mouseUp, false)
c.addEventListener("touchmove", mouseMove, false);
c.addEventListener("touchstart", mouseDown, false);

}


function mouseDown(downE) {
    window.console &&  console.log("down");
};


function mouseMove(moveE){
    window.console && console.log("move");
}


function mouseUp() {
    window.console && console.log("end");
}
```

I get both the start and end events, using both the MSPointer and the "normal" javascript touch events, however the "move" event doesn't register.

I'm sure it's something really simple I'm missing here, thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Have you tried to just register to "mousemove" event ? (yes I know it's touch but regular touch events are not implemented on Windows 8)

Comment: @Aerilys Yes, mousemove is implemented.  I just cut out everything not pertaining to touch directly.  And no, it doesn't work/fire.  And the documentation says that those MSPointer events are implemented in IE10?

Comment: It's weird since I'm able to handle touch events perfectly with MSPointer stuff. The following code works for me https://github.com/Neferetheka/Swype-gestures-for-WinJS/blob/master/swype.winjs.js

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but MSPointerUp and MSPointerDown work fine.  It's the MSPointerMove that doesn't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm assuming you are interacting with the HTML page in desktop IE on Windows 8. In desktop IE, the MSPointerMove is not firing on that canvas because the default behavior when the user moves their finger around on the screen is to pan the content. If you style the canvas with the following snippet your MSPointerMove event should be detected.

style="-ms-touch-action: none"

Here's a great article on how to get touch working on many browsers. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/19/handling-multi-touch-and-mouse-input-in-all-browsers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Slate 7 tablets have a bug in older versions of the drivers that might be relevant. I saw another answer tagged [internet-explorer-10] that had the details. Have you updated your driver?